# Tuleap Configuration - SVN Issue

Tags: svn, tuleap

I am trying to use Tuleap in my Organization, but facing some issue after configuration. 
Request you to please guide me in solving this issue and sure your guidance would help you us to use Tuleap inside our organization.

We have 2 issues which stopping us to proceed further,

1) We have installed/configured Tuleap, we created new project.

In Subversion tab (Inside tuleap), When I click Browse SVN Tree sub tab, it displays following error message.

---

An Exception Has Occured
The root "shortname" is unknown. If you believe the value is correct, then please double-check your configuration

HTTP Response Status

### 404 Repository not found.

2) After creating the project in Tuleap, I have to add the source files to the respective svn repository which comes along with Tuleap.

Step for adding files to repository.

1. Check out the repository using repository URL as working copy using Tortoise SVN.
2. Then I will create folders and add files to the folders.
3. After adding, I will commit the files to store it in repository.

Issue:
Now, I am not able to checkout the repository itself.

If I try to checkout the repository, following error is displayed.

Command                Checkout from http://tuleap.fresh.com/svnroot/demo1, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
Error                         Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/svnroot/demo1'
Error                         Additional errors:
Error                         PROPFIND request on '/svnroot/demo1' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed

Completed!

Dear Experts,

Request you to please guide us in fixing this issue, your support is required to implement the same in our Organization quickly. Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the output of /var/log/httpd/error_log when you attempt to checkout ?